# What's the best language for server-side backends required by iPhone apps?

Tags: java, iphone, ruby, scala

The server will be processing large amounts of data daily and needs to be fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best language is the language that you, and your team, know the best - you will do a better job writing your server in a language you are an expert in than a language you just picked up.

It also depends wildly on the details of your problem.  You mentioned "lots of data", but not what that means.  That could be 100MB a day, 1TB a day, 15PB a day?

Is this big batch processing, or lots of little interactive operations?

Of the three specific languages you tagged in, Java, Scala, and Ruby, all three are reasonable choices that real companies have been successful in the market.

JVM hosted languages are generally going to be "faster" than traditional MRI Ruby, and both Java and Scala are generally "faster" than JRuby, when it comes to raw CPU capabilities.

Of the three, Scala probably offers the least familiar, most challenging paradigm for developers unfamiliar with it, but also has very good parallel and concurrent programming tools available in the core compared to the other options.

Finally, your end results will be influenced as substantially, if not more so, by the rest of the ecosystem you choose - the web or message handling stack, the data storage engine, and other concerns.  They, perhaps, should dictate your language more than your language dictates your ecosystem.

Comment: The only reason for Scala to be "challenging" is to be boxed into other thinking ... or to jump immediately into scalaz O.o

Comment: Personally, I would agree with you - but of all the languages, it is the one that has the largest number of unfamiliar concepts, development paradigms, and features that are absent in the basic set of common languages - the Perl, Python, Ruby cluster, and the C/C++/Java cluster.  While it is true that it might be limited thinking, that is enough to make it a harder language to use out of the gate.

Comment: I should have been much more specific in my question, but I thank you for your informative answer.